# What is the url for mainnet?

Tags: endpoint

I am new to Solana Development, I was wondering, how can I make a change on the mainnet and not on the devnet. My target is to make transactions using python. I got some help but I have https://api.devnet.solana.com as the endpoint. How can I change it to mainet and not mainet-beta so that I can transfer SOL directly on the mainnet?

Comment: the SOL in mainnet beta is real. I could be wrong but I believe mainnet-beta and mainnet are the same thing ? they just haven't renamed it yet

Answer (score 5):

**Mainnet is mainnet-beta**. The `beta` will be removed from the name at some point when the Anza, Jump, and other core infrastructure engineers are happy. In Jan 2024 Solana has nearly a year of uptime, and [Toly tweeted](https://twitter.com/aeyakovenko/status/1750739649449123985):

> Beta ends when firedancer is stable and it’s running as a safety check on mainnet.

But for now, mainnet is still mainnet-beta.

The RPC URL to connect to mainnet is  `https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com` but keep in mind you might get rate limited when making too many RPC calls at times. So, its recommended if you are deploying anything for production use always get a private RPC connection. There are quite a few options :

- [Quicknode](https://www.quicknode.com/)
- [GenesysGo](https://twitter.com/GenesysGo)
- [Triton](https://rpcpool.com/#/)
- [Alchemy](https://www.alchemy.com/)

Answer (score 1):

here is the link to solana mainnet cluster
https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com